# Can I get Metadata of Files, or Stats of Files, Stored on Azure Databricks

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, databricks

As I mentioned in the title, I'm curious to know if I can get metadata on a bunch of files, basically all the files in a blob, which are loaded on Azure Databricks.  I'm hoping there is some kind of generic script that can be run to give stats on files (mostly CSV format).  I know it is pretty easy to get all kinds of stats on tables in SQL Server, which is also a Microsoft product.  Or, maybe there is some kind of report that can be generated to show metadata, stats, etc., of files.  Ultimately, I would like to get a list of files names, file sizes, and if possible, counts of nulls in fields and total counts of nulls, in all fields, in all files.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For files the only thing available is dbutils.fs.ls which will list files in a folder including the file size.

You cannot get stats on a csv file without opening it and performing a query - csv is a text file.

Formats such as parquet do store statistics of data distribution. There are probably python and scala libraries available that can read them for you if you really want to.

If you are registering the files as a table in Databricks (Hive) then there can be statistics generated for query optimisation. https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/spark-sql/language-manual/analyze-table.html

That link includes details of the DESCRIBE command to view them.

Like SQL Server table stats are distributions and are estimates only. They will not give you true null counts for example. Both use them to improve query performance, neither intend users to use the stats directly.

Also Databricks is not a Microsoft product.

Comment: Thanks for the info.  It all makes sense to me now.